# MS Excel - splitting formula and displaying the result

Tags: excel, split, formulas

I haven't found an answer to such a question but I might have lost something.

I have a sort of dataset in excel.
In many cases, this dataset’s variables fish their data from other linked worksheets.
To grab those data have been used formulas. 
The following  is an example of the formula:

```
 ='https://JohnSmith-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_smith/Documents/Documents/2018/SOFTWARE/Results/WORK/Consultation/[SDG_contacts.xlsx]NSO SDG Contact Person Info.'!$D$5&" " &'https://JohnSmith-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_smith/Documents/Documents/2018/SOFTWARE/Results/WORK/Consultation/[SDG_contacts.xlsx]NSO SDG Contact Person Info.'!$E$5&"; "&'https://JohnSmith-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_smith/Documents/Documents/2018/SOFTWARE/Results/WORK/Consultation/[SDG_contacts.xlsx]NSO SDG Contact Person Info.'!$H$5
```

In a particular case, a variable includes names and email address of contact persons separated by semicolon (e.g. John Smith; j.smith@gmail.com).

I have to split names from email address.
To make it easier, I have this: 

              `Contact
    John Smith; j.smith@gmail.com`

and I have to get this:

```
  Contact       Contact email
John Smith     j.smith@gmail.com
```

by splitting the formula in two.

More precisely, the formula above has to become as follows:

Name:

```
='https://JohnSmith-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_smith/Documents/Documents/2018/SOFTWARE/Results/WORK/Consultation/[SDG_contacts.xlsx]NSO SDG Contact Person Info.'!$D$3&" " &'https://JohnSmith-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_smith/Documents/Documents/2018/SOFTWARE/Results/WORK/Consultation/[SDG_contacts.xlsx]NSO SDG Contact Person Info.'!$E$3
```

Email:

```
='https://JohnSmith-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_smith/Documents/Documents/2018/SOFTWARE/Results/WORK/Consultation/[SDG_contacts.xlsx]NSO SDG Contact Person Info.'!$H$3
```

For a number of reason I have to keep the formula and the content displayed on the cells.

Of course I do not want to repeat this manually hundreds of times. Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe instead of concatenating the data into a  string with `&` you should reference the individual data cells from your data sheet instead? Seems like a pretty logical solution.

Comment: I'll also leave this [`SPLIT()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php) function here. Sounds like it should be useful

Comment: If the data has been finalized, you could delimit it using the semicolon, which is the separator in your case. Otherwise, if you want to do it with a formula, try searching semicolon in your cell using FIND function and then use the string functions LEFT, RIGHT and/or MID to extract the desired text (contact name, email, etc.). I'll illustrate further if you need help.